# Generate Angularjs app with latest unstable branch?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

Just started using Yeoman and loving it. However, I am building an app that depends on some Angular 1.1.x features (`ng-trim` and `ng-animate`), and the Angular-generator uses the latest stable branch as its default, which doesn't include these features.

In Yeoman, is there any way to generate an Angular app with the latest 'unstable' branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to update your bower.json and use an unofficial build of angular unstable:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "atizo/bower-angular-unstable#~1.1.5",
```

Then you have to rerun `bower install`.