# angular 1.1.x bower dependency configuration

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, bower

For my yeoman+angular app, I'm trying to add angular 1.1.5 to my bower dependency list.  Unfortunately, angular's github page has only provided a bower repository for 1.0.7.

One answer I've seen on [another stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809620/generate-angularjs-app-with-latest-unstable-branch) question is to fork angular 1.1.5 into my github account and reference it there.  Is there any other way to maintain a reference to an official angular release of 1.1.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `angular-unstable` bower package. https://github.com/johannestroeger/bower-angular-unstable

Comment: I replaced the angular package with this one successfully, but realized that many of the default packages installed using the angular-generator in yeoman listed angular 1.0.7 in it's dependency list (angular-cookies, angular-resource, etc).  I updated this manually, but all my changes were wiped out when I executed a subsequent `bower install` command.

Is the solution to this dependency issue also to create new repos that contain modified `bower.json` files?

Comment: You can install both angular and angular-unstable via bower, but only include angular in your page.

Answer (score 1):

1.1.5 is an unstable release, so it's not likely you'll be able to use it in a scenario like this in any official capacity.  You'll probably have to wait till some of the changes in this branch make it to the stable release for any kind of official repo.

However, forking GitHub is probably a good idea to temporarily allow you to use the 1.1.5 build.